# Why is gson changing my Base64 encodeing and how to prevent it

Tags: java, json, base64, gson

I have the following data

```
    String text = "ZG9udCB0b3VjaCBtZQ==";
    MqttMessageDTO data = new MqttMessageDTO("topic", text, "id", 1L);
    String a = gson.toJson(data);
```

Where `MqttMessageDTO` looks like

```
public class MqttMessageDTO {
  private String topic;
  private String base64EncodedMessage;
  private String externalVehicleIdentifier;
  private Long timestamp;
}
```

(excluding getters and constructor)

This generates the following output:

```
{"topic":"topic","base64EncodedMessage":"ZG9udCB0b3VjaCBtZQ\u003d\u003d","externalVehicleIdentifier":"id","timestamp":1}
```

Where the base64EncodedMessage field has been changed and `==` has been replaced with `\u003d\u003d`.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent this from happening. I dont want gson to make any changes while serializing and deserializing the `base64EncodedMessage` field.

Gson version:
2.8.5

Comment: Some characters are escaped so that they can be easily embedded into XHTML documents (to avoid conflicts). What version are using?

Comment: Its not just escaped its ascii encoded the ==?? This is never going to be embedded in XHTML so i dont want that.

Comment: You can bypass some of that by using `disableHtmlEscaping()` in `GsonBuilder`. As already mentioned, the JavaDoc confirms this: _By default, Gson escapes HTML characters such as < > etc._.